# How to merge elements of an array when they have equal properties and adding a property of these elements on SWIFT 5

Tags: arrays, swift

I need to merge elements of an array when they have equal properties and adding a property of these elements.

Example:

```swift
let manipulations: [Manipulation] = [
    .init(productName: "Beer", responsibleName: "John", grossWeight: 100.00, cleanWeight: 30.00),
    .init(productName: "Beer", responsibleName: "John", grossWeight: 200.00, cleanWeight: 50.00),
    .init(productName: "Food", responsibleName: "Michael", grossWeight: 100.00, cleanWeight: 20.00),
    .init(productName: "Food", responsibleName: "Michael", grossWeight: 400.00, cleanWeight: 100.00),
    .init(productName: "Object", responsibleName: "John", grossWeight: 400.00, cleanWeight: 100.00),
    .init(productName: "Beer", responsibleName: "John", grossWeight: 200.00, cleanWeight: 50.00),
    .init(productName: "Beer", responsibleName: "John", grossWeight: 200.00, cleanWeight: 50.00),
    .init(productName: "Beer", responsibleName: "John", grossWeight: 200.00, cleanWeight: 50.00),
    .init(productName: "Water", responsibleName: "John", grossWeight: 200.00, cleanWeight: 50.00)
]

// MARK: - What i need:

print(manipulations)
// [
// Manipulation.(productName: "Beer", responsibleName: "John", grossWeight: 900.00,
// cleanWeight: 230.00),
// Manipulation.(productName: "Food", responsibleName: "Michael", grossWeight: 500.00,
// cleanWeight: 120.00),
// Manipulation.(productName: "Object", responsibleName: "John", grossWeight: 400.00,
// cleanWeight: 100.00)
// ]
```

Comment: Why remove the `Manipulations` struct declaration? That just makes it harder for people to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a dictionary you can actually group all of the elements you want to sum by key:

```
struct ManipulationKey {
    let productName: String
    let responsibleName: String
}

extension ManipulationKey: Hashable {}


let groupedElements = Dictionary(grouping: manipulations) { element in
    return ManipulationKey(productName: element.productName, responsibleName: element.responsibleName)
}
```

When you have everything grouped you can simply loop through the keys/values and sum the weights:

```
let mergedManipulations = groupedElements.keys.map {

    var grossWeight = 0.0
    var cleanWeight = 0.0
    for manipulation in groupedElements[$0] ?? [] {
        grossWeight += manipulation.grossWeight
        cleanWeight += manipulation.cleanWeight
    }
    let newManipulation = Manipulation(
        productName: $0.productName,
        responsibleName: $0.responsibleName,
        grossWeight: grossWeight,
        cleanWeight: cleanWeight
    )
    return newManipulation
}
```

Comment: The only drawback here is that dictionary is an unordered collection.

Comment: The result (newElements) is an array so you can sort that by whatever you want. I probably could have picked a better name.

Comment: What I meant is if the result should keep the original collection order

Comment: this resulted in the same initial elements :/ but tnkss

Answer (score 0):

If the collection is always sorted and the order of the elements matter you can use reduce method to get and compare the last element of the result with the current element and if they are equal sum them otherwise append a new element. Something like:

```
extension BidirectionalCollection where Element == Manipulation, Index == Int {
    var summed: [Element] {
        return reduce(into: []) {
            if let lastElement = $0.last,
               let lastIndex = $0.indices.last,
                lastElement.productName == $1.productName,
                lastElement.responsibleName == $1.responsibleName {
                $0[lastIndex] = .init(
                    productName: lastElement.productName,
                    responsibleName: lastElement.responsibleName,
                    grossWeight: lastElement.grossWeight + $1.grossWeight,
                    cleanWeight: lastElement.cleanWeight + $1.cleanWeight
                )
            } else {
                $0.append($1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let summed = manipulations.summed
print(summed)
```

---

This will print

> [
> Manipulation(productName: "Beer", responsibleName: "John", grossWeight: 300.0, cleanWeight: 80.0),
> Manipulation(productName: "Food", responsibleName: "Michael", grossWeight: 500.0, cleanWeight: 120.0),
> Manipulation(productName: "Object", responsibleName: "John", grossWeight: 400.0, cleanWeight: 100.0)
> ]

---

edit/update:

If the elements are not sorted you need to sort them before summing the elements:

```
let manipulations = [
    ("Beer"  , "John",    100,  30),
    ("Beer"  , "John",    200,  50),
    ("Food"  , "Michael", 100,  20),
    ("Food"  , "Michael", 400, 100),
    ("Object", "John",    400, 100),
    ("Beer"  , "John",    200,  50),
    ("Beer"  , "John",    200,  50),
    ("Beer"  , "John",    200,  50),
    ("Water" , "John",    200,  50)
].map(Manipulation.init)
```

---

```
let summed = manipulations.sorted {
        ($0.productName, $0.responsibleName) < ($1.productName, $1.responsibleName)
}.summed
print(summed)
```

---

This will print:

> [
> Manipulation(productName: "Beer", responsibleName: "John", grossWeight: 900.0, cleanWeight: 230.0),
> Manipulation(productName: "Food", responsibleName: "Michael", grossWeight: 500.0, cleanWeight: 120.0),
> Manipulation(productName: "Object", responsibleName: "John", grossWeight: 400.0, cleanWeight: 100.0),
> Manipulation(productName: "Water", responsibleName: "John", grossWeight: 200.0, cleanWeight: 50.0)
> ]

---

Another option as already suggested is to make your struct conform to Hashable and use a dictionary to keep track of the elements indices:

```
struct Manipulation {
   let productName: String
   let responsibleName: String
   var grossWeight: Double = 0
   var cleanWeight: Double = 0
}

extension Manipulation: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        (lhs.productName, lhs.responsibleName) == (rhs.productName, rhs.responsibleName)
    }
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(productName)
        hasher.combine(responsibleName)
    }
}
```

And your computed property would look something like:

```
extension BidirectionalCollection where Element == Manipulation, Index == Int {
    var summed: [Element] {
        var dict: [Element: Int] = [:]
        return reduce(into: []) {
            if let index = dict[$1] {
                $0[index].grossWeight += $1.grossWeight
                $0[index].cleanWeight += $1.cleanWeight
            } else {
                dict[$1] = $0.count
                $0.append($1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that didn't work, when I have a lot of the same elements, it ends up not merging them all.

Comment: I edited my example for this question to make the example clearer.

Comment: Well you just need to sort the elements before summing them.